# Exe file to emulate keystrokes you put in a script. How to?

Tags: powershell, script, emulator

I want to make an .exe file, that when executed, acts like a User made inputs to a **HID**. I know this is possible with Sendkeys method with Powershell, but i couldn't get it working for me. I've done some research and i have been able to make script that print out whole strings, but I want to emulate the simultanius press of Win + ctrl + arrow-left. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A tool more adapted to the task is
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
It comes with the possibility to
[Convert a Script to an EXE (Ahk2Exe)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe).

You may use the
[Pulover's Macro Creator](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=143)
to capture events and include them in a AutoHotkey script.

You will find much information in the AutoHotkey website. For specific problems,
Google is your friend.